# Getting cookie header without using blocking scala.concurrent.Await

Tags: scala, spray

I am using Spray Framework to get the JSESSIONID from Cookie Header.

I can get the JSESSIONID by using `scala.concurrent.Await` as follows:

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive  

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post(Uri(url)))
val hs : HttpResponse  = scala.concurrent.Await.result(responseFuture, 5.seconds)        

val sessionId: Option[String] = hs.headers.collectFirst {
      case h: `Set-Cookie` if h.cookie.name == "JSESSIONID" => 
      h.cookie.content
    }

println("sessionId: "+sessionId.get)
```

However, the above code doesn't look good due to following reasons:

Blocking with Await is a no-no and calling get on an Option is also ill-advised.

So I tried the following:

```
responseFuture.onComplete(response => {
              val cookies = response.get.headers.collect {
              case c: `Set-Cookie` => c.cookie.content
              }
              println("cookies: "+cookies(0))
          })
```

But I can't use `cookies(0)` outside of `onComplete` method block as its scope is limited within that block.

Please advise?

Comment: have you tried using Spray's onComplete directive?

Comment: See my question. I mentioned that part. When I use `onComplete` then I can't use `cookies(0)` outside of onComplete method block as its scope is limited within that block.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, just wanted to make sure whether you're using Future's onComplete(which is what I understood by looking at your solution) or Spray's onComplete directive. Because if you are using Spray's directive in your route, you can generate your final response from that onComplete only.

Comment: ok I don't know about Spray `onComplete`. I am using Future `onComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do something like this by Spray's onComplete directive:

```
onComplete(responseFuture) {
case scala.util.Success(response) => 
 val cookies = response.get.headers.collect {
          case c: `Set-Cookie` => c.cookie.content
          }
complete(OK,"response")

case scala.util.Failure(ex) => 
 complete(InternalServerError,"error")
}
```

You can find the documentation for the same here: [Spray onComplete](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/)

You can generate your response inside the onComplete block.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: How to import `onComplete` and `complete`. I am getting compilation errors on them. I tried importing `import akka.dispatch.OnComplete` but that doesn't work.

Comment: It has been a long when I worked on spray, I migrated my stuff from spray to akka-http(as spray is no longer maintained). So I'm not sure about the import. Try this import spray.routing.directives._

Comment: If still, the problem persists with importing, you can clarify once.

Comment: Yes, its still there. I can't get through it. I think I need to bind each call within Future onComplete for now.

Comment: But I, suppose that won't help as Future onComplete won't return anything, how you'll generate the response?

Comment: Either I will put all code within Future onComplete so that I can use its generated response or I can use Await with atmost wait time of 5 seconds.

Comment: I guess I find out the import, and also i've edited my answer, hope this might help:
import spray.routing for directives, and import spray.http.StatusCodes._ for response status code.

Comment: here is how you can use onComplete: 
        spray.routing.directives.FutureDirectives.onComplete(Future(""))

Comment: There is still error on import of 'complete'. However, error that was coming in 'onComplete' is now no more.

Comment: Ok this is also done. But the return type is a `<function1>`. How to convert it into proper string.

Comment: you must be accessing the cookies inside some route, right ?

Comment: No, I am getting future from URL like this: `val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post(Uri(url)))`

Comment: Then are you generating any response HttpResponse based on this?

Comment: yes, see your answer's first line which has `responseFuture` as parameter. It is that response generated from:  `val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post(Uri(url)))`